Data Quality - classification, analysis and references
Im working on a data quality project that aims to improve the processing and handling of data for my business.
I am looking for references or learning materials that will help me classify the typical data quality issues that occur in data processing environments.
The work is financial primarily, pulling in instrument prices, security static .
Data quality checks range from basics such as row counts: after processing your staging table and target tables have the same row counts.
To checking that the change in a position size is within expected limits.
What I am trying to find is references that would allow me investigate general data quality problem categories and techniques to both recognise, report and ultimately look at resolving them.
Perhaps this is not the best forum for this, but data science in general has a focus on getting "clean" data.
